# Google Sheets, Trying to reference a cell in another sheet using a formula to determine the row number

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to reference cells from another sheet in the same workbook in Google Sheets, but I don't want to have to select the exact cell for every cell reference.  What I need to do is reference a cell in another workbook for which the row number is 4 times the row number in which the formula appears.  For example, in Sheet 1, cell A1, I could use =Sheet2!$A$4, but I don't want to have to do that all the way down my sheet.  What I want to do is write a formula that tells the formula "go to Sheet2 and give me the value of the cell in column A that has a row number that is 4 times the current row number." Can't figure out how to do it though.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=INDEX(ROW(Sheet2!A:A) * 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter()`, like this:

```
=filter( 
  Sheet2!A1:A, 
  match( 
    row(Sheet2!A1:A), 
    4 * sequence(rows(Sheet2!A1:A)), 
    0 
  ) 
)
```

This formula gets *every* fourth value from Sheet2 in one go.